# Integrating Premium Rate Shipping with Shipwire

Tags: shipping

Have a Magento integration that's using Premium Rate for shipping.  The shipping method for 2 Day shipping is `premiumrate_2day`.  Shipwire expects the `shipping_method` value in the order API that it pings to contain `2D`.

It looks like I will need to rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api` class in order to map our shipping methods to the ones that they expect.  This seems like a bit of a heavy hammer for what I would have imagined would be a pretty common scenario.

Can someone tell me if there are a couple of configuration options I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Can you not just extend Premium Rate and override or change the `premiumrate_2day` option to just `2D`?

Comment: Maybe. But from the looks of it, the shipping method is baked into the premium rate table and its also saved on all the previous orders. So I felt like there would be a lot of places to change it and test if I went that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the algorithm column use m=. This will make the shipping method be premiumrate_ e.g. premiumrate_2D.

See here for further details:

https://webshopapps.bloomfire.com/posts/481594

You cant get rid of the prefix as magento uses this in its internal processing. Well you can, but its harder.